# TypeError: decoding to str: need a bytes-like object, tuple found SQLite,Python

Tags: python, database, sqlite

```
import sqlite3
from math import pow
import numpy as np



def create_connection():
    objekts = ("vienādojumi{Ivo}.db")

    try: 
        conn = sqlite3.connect(objekts)  

    except Exception as err:  
        print("Radās izņēmums izveidojot savienojumu", err)

    else:
            for x in np.arange(-10,10,0.0001):
                string =("Insert into Aprēķins (x,y) values (",format(x),", ")
                query = str(string,format(aprekins(x)))
                cur = conn.cursor()  
                cur.execute(query)
                row = cur.fetchall()
                print(row)
            print("Pabeigts")

            cur.close()

    finally:
        conn.close()

    return conn


def aprekins(x):
    return -13+pow(x,2)+13*x+26
create_connection()
```

I tried changing tuples to strings and making different strings, but nothing worked, so I stopped working on this code with the error that I needed a byte-like object. The query has to be a string.

Error message:
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
   line 37, in <module>
    create_connection()
  line 20, in create_connection
    query = str(string,format(aprekins(x)))
TypeError: decoding to str: need a bytes-like object, tuple found

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Please add the complete error log so it will be clearer where exactly the error is getting thrown.

Comment: Please provide the entire error message (formatted as code for readability) inside the question, not in the title. Include the traceback. There is important information missing from your abbreviated error message, such as line numbers.

Comment: line 20, in create_connection
    query = str(string,format(aprekins(x)))
TypeError: decoding to str: need a bytes-like object, tuple found

Comment: @IvoSorokins please add it in your questions body. Not in the comments.

Comment: @IvoSorokins what exactly is the indented behavior of this line - `query = str(string,format(aprekins(x)))`

Comment: @Ritwik G it makes so code is read like string because otherwise it will read it as tuple and sqlite3 query doesn't read tuple's.

Comment: @IvoSorokins I meant how that `query` is supposed to look like?

Comment: Anyway if you are using python3. I think replacing that `query` with `query = f"Insert into Aprēķins (x,y) values ({x}, {aprekins(x)})"` and removing the `string` before it should solve the issue for you.

Comment: 2 columns x and y. X is defined by for loop, y by formula y=-13x^2+13x+26

Comment: @IvoSorokins I believe you have tried to follow the way how you might print the string inside `print` function to format your query. And it is causing the error for you.

Answer (score 0):

In your code the line below

```
string =("Insert into Aprēķins (x,y) values (",format(x),", ")
```

here the type of variable string is `tuple`
And when you try to create query with

```
query = str(string,format(aprekins(x)))
```

your expectation might be to format the string. But what is actually happening is the `str` is trying to decode `string` which is a tuple using an encoding type. In your case what ever the output of `format(aprekins(x))` will be considered as encoding type.

For demonstration try the below code and you will get the same error

```
str(('a','b'), "utf-8")
```

If this is not clear for you before the `query` formation try printing the `type` of your string

Answer (score 0):

The query should be a string, and I assume that you are trying to format the pair `(x, aprekins(x))` into it. But you used a wrong syntax.

It should be:

```
            string ="Insert into Aprēķins(x,y) values ({}, {})"
            query = string.format(x, aprekins(x))
```

Anyway, as the query is not a SELECT, `fetchall` will consistently return an empty string.

But directly inserting values inside queries is not recommended. No problem here, because you have full control on the values, but it is frowned upon on other context because it was the cause of [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Parameterized queries are now prefered:

```
            query ="Insert into Aprēķins(x,y) values (:1, :2)"
            cur = conn.cursor()  
            cur.execute(query, (x, aprekins(x)))
```

It can even be used to speed up insertion by having the SQL engine to process the query once and then use it with a bunch of parameters (also called *prepared* queries):

```
...
else:
        query ="Insert into Aprēķins(x,y) values (:1, :2)"
        #query = string.format(x, aprekins(x))
        cur = conn.cursor()  
        cur.executemany(query, ((x, aprekins(x))
                                 for x in np.arange(-10,10,0.0001)))
        row = cur.execute('SELECT * FROM Aprēķins').fetchall()
        print(row)
        print("Pabeigts")
        ...
```

But it any case, you have to commit the INSERT queries before closing the database connection. If you forget that, an implicit rollback is done and your database is still empty:

```
        ...
        print("Pabeigts")

        cur.close()
        conn.commit()
finally:
    conn.close()
```

Comment: cur.executemany(query,(x, aprekins(x)))
ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type

Comment: @IvoSorokins did you use my text for query?

Comment: Yes @Serge Ballesta I did, it still didn't store any values into the database .

Comment: @IvoSorokins I could reproduce in a different environment with a true persistent database while my initial tests only use an in memory base and only accepted Latin1 characters. The problem was the missing commit as shown in my edit.